# Sending mails with grails mail plugin in groovy class - null config error

Tags: grails, plugins, groovy, sendmail

I get the error "Caused by NullPointerException: null ->>  64 | getMailConfig in grails.plugin.mail.MailService". I have configured the config.groovy as per the documentation provided by mail plugin.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Find my config.groovy code below.

```
grails
{

    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
        password = "xxxxxx"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
      }
}
```

Find my groovy class code below.

```
package common

import grails.plugin.mail.*;

public class FlowSchedule implements Job {

    def mailService = new MailService()

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
           throws JobExecutionException {

                    //some extra logic here
                   sendEmail(schedulerEntry.name,schedulerEntry.email)

    }
    def sendEmail(String name,String email)
    {

            mailService.sendMail {
                to "amith.ravuru@citrix.com"
                subject "Hello Amith"
                body 'this is some text'
            }
    }
}
```

Complete Error trace:

```
Error |
2014-07-14 12:41:00,041 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] ERROR core.ErrorLogger  - Job     (group.Job_1 threw an exception.

Message: Job threw an unhandled exception.
   Line | Method
->> 213 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

**^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: null**

**->>  64 | getMailConfig in grails.plugin.mail.MailService**

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    59 | sendMail in     ''
|    94 | sendEmail in common.FlowSchedule$$EOk1HyVA
|    79 | execute in     ''
|   202 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `grailsApplication.config.grails.mail` in your job and see if it comes out correct?

Comment: No, grailsApplication was coming as Null. I solved it by moving my code into a new controller and called the function from class present in src/groovy folder. No injection was happening when my groovy class was present in src/groovy folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by moving the sendEmail part to a controller. Then, call the controller method from any class in src/groovy. Because, in controllers, grailsApplication can be injected using def grailsApplication. Please find the controller code below.

```
   class SendMailController 
   {

   def grailsApplication

   def sendEmail(String name,String email,String mailsubject)
   {

       if(email != null)
       {


           try
           {

               sendMail {
                   to email 
                   from "exabgpnotifier@gmail.com"
                   subject "ExaBGP Notification"
                   body "Hello "+name+"\n\n"+ mailsubject +" \n\nRegards,\nExaBGP Team"
                }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               e.printStackTrace()
               println "ERROR!!: Unable to send the notification to email "+ finalemaillist.toString()
           }
       }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this plugin injects mailService into your application. So instead of creating service with constructor like you've done:

```
def mailService = new MailService()
```

Just declare the field and let DI mechanism to do the work of injecting the value:

```
def mailService
```

The remaining part of your code looks okay. Think about changing the name of `sendMail` method, now it's a bit confusing when you've got the same names for your method and the one from mailService.

Hope it'll help!

Comment: I get the below error saying that cannot invoke method sendMail on null object if i use def mailService.                                ^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sendMail() on null object
->>  91 | sendEmail in common.FlowSchedule

Comment: What's the location of FlowSchedule file? Could you try to rename the file to FlowScheduleJob?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work:

```
grails
{

    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
        password = "xxxxxx"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
      }
}
```

That is valid code but doesn't do what you intend.  The opening curly brace after `grails` needs to be on the same line so the closure is treated as an argument to the `grails` method.

```
grails {

    mail {
        host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        port = 465
        username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
        password = "xxxxxx"
        props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
      }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested but i get the same error as i mentioned before.  "Caused by NullPointerException: null
->>  64 | getMailConfig in grails.plugin.mail.MailService"

Answer (score -1):

Open you resources.groovy file and put this entry.

```
import common.FlowSchedule
beans = {
   // make sure you import flow schedule class
   flowSchedule(FlowSchedule) {
      mailService = ref('mailService')        
  }
}
```

Then in your class.

```
package common

import grails.plugin.mail.*;

public class FlowSchedule implements Job {

  def mailService

  public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
       throws JobExecutionException {

                //some extra logic here
               sendEmail(schedulerEntry.name,schedulerEntry.email)

  }
  def sendEmail(String name,String email)
  {

        mailService.sendMail {
            to "amith.ravuru@citrix.com"
            subject "Hello Amith"
            body 'this is some text'
        }
  }
}
```

When you need flow schedule in any controller or service then just do this

```
class MyService {

   def flowSchedule

   def myMethod() {
      flowSchedule.sendEmail('test','test@test.com')
   } 
}
```